# subprocess call opening .txt file but not writing into it

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I'm trying to write GPS data into a CSV through Python 3 with RaspberryPi. Writing the file works when the commands are run directly through the console, but when it is in python, the file opens and then returns an error (usually that another process is running). We wrote in another line to kill the process, but it's still not writing to the CSV. Any tips?

```
import math
import time
import os
os.system('sudo fuser -k/dev/ttyAMAO')
os.system('stty -F /dev/ttyAMAO 9600')
os.system('sudo gpsd /dev/ttyAMAO -F /var/run/gpsd.sock')
os.system('sudo gpsmon /dev/ttyAMAO -l /home/pi/Desktop/GPSDATA.txt')
```

Comment: I don't see the CSV in the commands.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that [os.system()](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/os.html#os.system) executes the command in a subshell. This means that the PID of the shell executing the command will changes at each command.

A simple solution is to chain the commands in you call to `os.system`.